# Xamarin and handheld devices

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, handhelddevice

Hello I have to develope a cross app for handheld devices. Is it possible to use Xamarin.forms in visual studio 2017 to create and deploy it?

Comment: that is specifically what Xamarin is designed to do

Comment: Good to know thanks. I thought that Xamarin was more about smart phones, tablets and desktop.

Comment: well, when you said "handheld device" I assumed you meant a phone or tablet.  If it's not that, please be more specific about what your requirements are.

Comment: Is there an example of hello world to deploy with barcode scanning?

Comment: As handheld device I mean those mini computers used in warehouses. They are used for scanning products barcodes to create inventories

Comment: if it runs Android, then the answer is probably yes.  And sample apps are available on the Xamarin site

Comment: It’s something like this https://visionid.ie/search/productResults?keywords=&man=Datalogic&cat=18&submit=Search&gclid=CjwKCAiA0uLgBRABEiwAecFnkxdbHD-4cJC7Jz0bUJ5W0v82O2oDdZ1uKz88lE5lGP7Q6vIYTwEyMhoCuXYQAvD_BwE

Comment: most of those appear to run Windows CE or Windows 6.5, both of which are incredibly outdated systems

Comment: You’re right maybe I picked the wrong link. I’m going to find a more updated link as soon as I contacted the customer and come back to you. I’m pretty sure he wouldn’t buy a device so old. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Handheld devices are older than any smartphone we knows and use Windows ce as OS. You can use c++ to develop applications for such a devices.